# PHP: Set timestamp on sideload and on form submit?

Tags: php, forms, timestamp

How is it possible to have two different timestamps in a form? The first one has to have the value from the sideload and the second one from the submission, so that I can compare the values and check if the form is sent between a period of time?

Comment: Just keep it on the server-side, in for example a session variable.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to maintain the creation time in a session variable:

```
$_SESSION['createdAt'] = time();
```

When the form is submitted, you can always get the timestamp for the submission time and compare the two:

```
$submittedAt = time();
$timeToFillForm = $submittedAt - $_SESSION['createdAt'];
```

If you really want it in a form, you could add a hidden input during form creation (instead of storing the 'createdAt' timestamp in session).

```
<input type='hidden' name='createdAt' value='<?php echo time() ?>' />
```

And on submission:

```
$submittedAt = time();
$timeToFillForm = $submittedAt - $_POST['createdAt'];
```

But if you are dead set on having two timestamps in a form, you may need some JS/jQuery:

```
 $("#myForm").submit(function(e) {
      var input = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "submittedAt").val(Date.now());
      $("#myForm").append(input);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

> so that I can compare the values and check if the form is sent between a period of time?

basically you want to know **since how much time** was the form sent to the client? You can send an input with the initial request time to calculate how much time has elapsed when you receive the form.

```
<?php
echo '<input name="INITIAL_REQUEST_TIME" type="hidden" value="'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'].'">';
```

wen receiving the form, the elapsed time is:

```
<?php
echo date( 'H:i:s', $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] - $_POST['INITIAL_REQUEST_TIME'] );
```